# JHipster 6.0.1: Could not resolve propdeps-plugin

Tags: jhipster

Just recently generate jhipster online v.6.0.1 and could not resolve io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.10.RELEASE.

Anyone faced the same issue?

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'abc'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2100(DefaultConfiguration.java:138)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.10.RELEASE.
Required by:
    project :
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.10.RELEASE.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.10.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.10.RELEASE.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/io/spring/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.10.RELEASE/propdeps-plugin-0.0.10.RELEASE.pom'. Received status code 500 from server: Internal Server Error
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.processResponse(HttpClientHelper.java:160)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHead(HttpClientHelper.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getMetaData(HttpResourceAccessor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.getMetaData(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.getMetaData(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:201)
    ... 190 more
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Add more details of the issue that you are facing.Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting for 1 hours this was not reproducible anymore. It seems that the problem was caused by spring repo issue.